# How can you develop an algorithm for a developer review queue rotation?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose you have developers `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` and they review each other's work.

How can you develop an algorithm to generate a review rotation telling each developer whose work they have to review each week AND satisfy these criteria:

- You cannot review the same person two weeks in a row
- There cannot be closed loops (`A` reviews `B`, `B` reviews `A`)
- It would be nice if you review each other developer once before you start repeating.

I think I can make it work with an odd number of developers, but I am struggling with an even number.

Comment: Use `ROT13` as inspiration. Or rather, `ROT1`, `ROT2`, ...

Comment: And to add randomization to it, use `ROT` on a randomly ordered initial set (i.e. instead of ABCDEF use some permutation of it as the intial set).

Comment: @G.Bach what benefit does randomization bring to the algorithm?

Comment: @GavinMiller Nothing that was requested by mdobrinin, but if they don't want to review in cycles, they can use that.

Comment: I am not so sure that `ROT13` will satisfy the property that there can be no closed loops. See Gavin Miller's answer, which essentially `ROT1`, which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go the nieve route and rotate through a circular array. So week 1 everyone reviews the person to their right + 0. Week 2 everyone reviews the person to their right + 1. Week 3, right + 2, etc.

```
Week 1:
  A -> B
  B -> C
  ...
  F -> A
Week 2:
  A -> C
  B -> D
  ...
  F -> B
```

Comment: This in fact does **NOT work**. See Week 3: `A` reviews `D`, `D` reviews `A`.

Comment: @mdobrinin: However, this scheme can easily be fixed if you're willing to drop one of your requirements (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute-force in Haskell (takes about 10 seconds to get going).

Code:

```
import Control.Monad (guard, replicateM)

developers = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

combinations = filter (\x -> head x /= last x) . replicateM 2 $ developers

makeWeek week =
  if length week == length developers
     then [week]
     else do
       review <- combinations
       guard (notElem (take 1 review) (map (take 1) week)
              && notElem (drop 1 review) (map (drop 1) week)
              && notElem (reverse review) week
              && notElem review week)
       makeWeek (review:week)

solve = solve' [] where
  solve' weeks =
    if length weeks == length developers - 1
       then [weeks]
       else do
         week' <- makeWeek []
         guard (all (\x -> notElem x (concat . take (length developers - 1) $ weeks)) week')
         solve' (week':weeks)
```

Sample Output:

```
*Main> solve
[[[["F","B"],["E","A"],["D","C"],["C","E"],["B","D"],["A","F"]]
 ,[["F","C"],["E","B"],["D","A"],["C","D"],["B","F"],["A","E"]]
 ,[["F","A"],["E","C"],["D","B"],["C","F"],["B","E"],["A","D"]]
 ,[["F","E"],["E","D"],["D","F"],["C","B"],["B","A"],["A","C"]]
 ,[["F","D"],["E","F"],["D","E"],["C","A"],["B","C"],["A","B"]]],...etc
```

Comment: A developer will review the same person for the whole week. What I meant is that at the same time, the person you are reviewing cannot be reviewing you.

Comment: So does the output sample provide what you asked for? (It is just the first of a stream of five-week lists.) In five weeks: no reviews of the same person two weeks in a row, no closed loops,
and each developer is reviewed once.

Comment: The output does, but I was more looking for a simple algorithm than a brute force program. This is a not a theoretical problem and so the solution must be easy for a person to replicate!

Answer (score 1):

There is simple [round-robin tournament algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm) to get all possible pairs without repetitions.

```
Arrange developers in two columns, left column reviews right one.
Fix A place
Move all others in cyclic way.

A->F
B->E 
C->D

A->B
C->F 
D->E

A->C
D->B 
E->F

A->D
E->C 
F->B

A->E
F->D 
B->C
```

Comment: `A->F` means `A` reviews `F` and `F` reviews `A`? That is a violation of the requirement.

Comment: @mdobrinin  No, we can use rotated (cyclic) right column as reviewers of left column

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution inspired by the Round Robin rotation.

For Developers `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`

You fix a developer, say `A`. Then rotate the rest in a clockwise manner.

Then:

- Everyone on the top row reviews the person below them
- Everyone on the bottom row review the person above and to the right diagonally of them

**Week 1:**

```
A B C
D E F

AD
BE
CF
DB
EC
FA
```

**Week 2:**

```
A D B
E F C

AE
DF
BC
ED
FB
CA
```

**Week 3:**

```
A E D
F C B

AF
EC
DB
FE
CD
BA
```

**Week 4:**

```
A F E
C B D

AC
FB
ED
CF
BE
DA
```

**Week 5:**

```
A C F
B D E

AB
CD
FE
BC
DF
EA
```

Although it still exhibits unwanted properties where some people will never meet others such as `B` avoiding `D`.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that by *closed loops*, you refer to cycles of length exactly 2. That is, it is allowed that `A` reviews `B`, `B` reviews `C` and `C` reviews `A`.

Let `n` be the number of people, and let `0, ..., n-1` be their names.

Week 1:
Person `i` reviews the code of person `(i + 1) % n`.

Week 2: Person `i` reviews the code of person `(i + 2) % n`.

...

Week `n/2`: Person `i` **cannot review** the code of person `(i + n/2) % n`, since this would cause a closed loop. Therefore, person `i` instead reviews the code of person `(i + n/2 + 1) % n`.

Week `n/2 + 1`: Person `i` reviews the code of person `(i + n/2 + 2) % n`.

...

Week `n - 1`: Person `i` reviews the code of person `(i + 1) % n` again, everything starts over.

**Note**: your last (optional) requirement (each person reviews every other person before the cycle starts again) is violated. For `n = 2` and `n = 4`, no solution exists that satisfy all requirements anyway. The base case `n = 2` is trivial. Consider the case `n = 4`: If you want to avoid closed loops, at least one person has to review the same person twice in a row. (Just enumerate all possible review relationships to see this).

If you really need your last requirement, you'll have to go with @groovy's solution. I'll leave mine here since it's very easy to compute.

Comment: This seems to be the same as Gavin Miller's answer in that you just skip the offending weeks.

Comment: @mdobrinin: Indeed. I wrote a seperate answer because I wanted to make the assumptions explicit and show the tradeoff between taking/leaving the optional requirement.